# Regex extract number for RewriteRule

Tags: regex, numbers, extract, mod-rewrite

For http://macintosh.local/clientname/102
I can get the numeric reference (3 digits) like this:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([0-9]{3}+)/?$ album.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

Now I want to get my reference in my SEO URL:
http://macintosh.local/clientname/102-some-keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace /? with .*

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([0-9]{3}+).*$ album.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your existing regex should work just fine. It won't pick up non-numeric characters, after all.